# Why is there no identity Conversion in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scala-3

Scala doesn't support implicit conversion chaining (for good reason). There are some unfortunate cases when designing an API that provided an implicit conversion where you need it to chain.

This is fairly easy to workaround with Scala 2 implicits by allowing there to be another implicit conversion as an argument. For example:

```scala
  implicit def fromUndefOr[A, Result](j: UndefOr[A])(implicit conv: A => TypedReactElement[Result]): TypedReactElement[Result] =
    j.fold(null.asInstanceOf[TypedReactElement[Result]])(conv)
```

In Scala 3 this might look something like:

```
  given fromOption[A, Result](using conv: Conversion[A, TypedReactElement[Result]]): Conversion[Option[A], TypedReactElement[Result]] =
    _.fold(null.asInstanceOf[TypedReactElement[Result]])(conv)
```

However there is one major downside with using Scala 3's `Conversion`. There is no identity conversion. This means that trivial cases will fail:

```scala
def mayConvert[A, B](using conv: Conversion[A, B])(a: A): B =
  conv(a)

val noConversion: Int = mayConvert(123)
// No given instance of type Conversion[A, B] was found for parameter conv of method mayConvert in object Playground
```

This is very annoying and yet one more reason to stick with `implicit def`s.

Is there any good reason for this?

Comment: TBH I think you are using the conversion wrong. The only 2 things that is is supposed to do, is to enable things like `val a: A; def f(b: B); f(a) /* convert A to B*/` and to **not** get confused with `Function[A, B]` (to avoid accidents like `implicit List[String]]` becoming `Int => String` conv). It is NOT supposed to be derived, it is supposed to be provided specifically for specific types where author know it is safe. If you want to perform derivations... I would suggest creating a dedicated type class, because you want to make possible OOTB things that people *rely on* not being possible.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like what you actually want is to have some kind of parsing typeclass, like a json `Decoder[A]`. `Conversion` isn't meant for this and it's extremely user-hostile api design to use it like that

Comment: I am using for the situation you are describing. `TypedReactElement[Result]` is a new type that captures some type information. I have conversions that I know are safe to go from `A` to `TypedReactElement[Result]`. That part is totally fine. I can call `def f(a: TypedReactElement[Result])` with an `A` provided there is a conversion. Hopefully you agree nothing strange there. I should also be able to call `def f(a: js.UndefOr[TypedReactElement[Result]])` with an `A` too. I could do the same thing with a `Converter` typeclass and then have a `Conversion` if a `Converter` exists or just use defs.

Comment: It's not even like I came up with this particular one myself. Here is the Slinky version:
`  @inline implicit def jsUndefOrToElement[E](j: js.UndefOr[E])(implicit cv: E => ReactElement): ReactElement = {
    val x = if (j.isDefined) cv(j.get) else null.asInstanceOf[ReactElement]
    x
  }`